# PL/LUA type ERROR: [pllua]: raw datum expected for datum conversion, got number

Tags: postgresql, lua, pllua

I have the following PL/LUA function (PostgreSQL 9.6) for computing factorial, which takes an integer as input and need to return a `BIGINT` as a result. I couldn't figure out how to cast the return value properly though.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION factorial_lua(n integer) RETURNS bigint AS $$
  if (n == 0) then return 1 end
  return factorial_lua(n-1)*n
$$ LANGUAGE pllua;
```

Evaluating the function generates an error as follows:

```
=> SELECT factorial_lua(3);
ERROR:  [pllua]: raw datum expected for datum conversion, got number
```

Can someone explain how to fix the above function and cast return type appropriately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, the problem seems to be that pllua cannot handle the PostgreSQL `BIGINT` type as integral values, and treat them as "userdata values". Therefore, in the line:

```
return factorial_lua(n-1)*n
```

PL/Lua couldn't do arithmetic between the [raw datum userdata](http://pllua.projects.pgfoundry.org/) and the integer `n`. The function will work if both the input value `n` and the return type is defined as `integer`.